# Windows javac path env issues

Tags: java, eclipse

I have my `javac` under my project directory. Lets say at `C:\workspace\myworkspace\java\bin\javac`

what i want to do is, in ant, use that particular javac for building. so i do

```
<exec executable="java\bin\javac">
<exec>
```

but my eclipse keep complaining

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\workspace\myworkspace\build.xml:7: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java\bin\javac" (in directory "C:\workspace\myworkspace"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

what is wrong? I went to directory C:\workspace\myworkspace\java\bin\ and do javac and it works,
but i cant do 
    `C:\workspace\myworkspace\java\bin\java`  from command line.

What is different on Windows? I normally work on linux so I don't know how to make it right on windows.

To add a bit more, I don't want add this java to my $PATH, because it's particular for this project only, and i dont want to mess up with my other java executables.

Comment: Normally you wouldn't install javac in the workspace to start with - the installer should put it in Program Files... why have you put it under your workspace? And what happens if you *do* run `c:\workspace\myworkspace\java\bin\javac` from the command line?

Comment: windows command line cant run it too. (says "... is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.) But if i do to that directory, and do javac it works.

Comment: Read more about [Ant javac task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)

Comment: @SteelMan: Can you show a copy of a command line session? It would be interesting to see this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Two potential problems...

Firstly, it's possible that this:

```
<exec executable="java\bin\javac">
```

... is making Ant look for a file called `java\bin\javac` within the directory `c:\workspace\myworkspace`, where it doesn't exist. It's `javac` within `c:\workspace\myworkspace\java\bin`, which isn't quite the same thing.

As per the [`exec` documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) you might want to use a `<property>` with a `location` attribute to resolve the file.

Secondly, it's possible that it's being confused by looking for `javac` when the executable is *actually* called `javac.exe`. The `.exe` extension is checked for by the command shell, but I don't think `Runtime.exec` will do the same thing.

Also, as Braj mentioned in comments, you'd be better off using [Ant's built-in support for `javac`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)...